# Bootstrap3 CSS - columns not resizing properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to bootstrap but it's fairly easy to use. 
My understanding is you define multiple width classes in one div and that handles site responsiveness.

However, my rows aren't resizing correctly when I switch from desktop to mobile view.

I have two columns, that I want on the same row on large and medium screens, and on two rows for small and extra small screens.

My code is as follows for the divs:

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row vertical-align">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 text-center">
                <img class="dream" src="~/Content/Images/Pokemon/Dream/@(Model.dexNo).png" />
                <img class="sprite" src="~/Content/Images/Pokemon/Sprites/@(Model.spriteString)" />
                <div style="display:block">
                    <img class="type" src="~/Content/Images/Types/@(Model.type1Id).png" />
                    @if (Model.type2Id.HasValue)
                {
                        <img class="type" src="~/Content/Images/Types/@(Model.type2Id.Value).png" />
                    }
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-12">
                <h4 class="pull-right">no. @Model.dexNoThreeDigits</h4>
                @if (Model.isOwner)
                {
                    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#renameModal" style="color:black;cursor:pointer;text-decoration:none;"><h1 class="large-text text-center">@Model.nickName</h1></a>
                }
                else
                {
                    <h1 class="large-text text-center">@Model.nickName</h1>
                }
                <h1 class="large-text text-center" style="font-style:italic;opacity:0.2;position:relative;top:-34px;left:81px;">the @Model.speciesName</h1>
                
                <h3 class="no-bottom-margin">Level @Model.level</h3>

                <div class="progress no-bottom-margin">
                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="@Model.expToNextLevelPercent"
                         aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:@(Model.expToNextLevelPercent)%">
                        <span class="sr-only">@(Model.expToNextLevelPercent)% Complete</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                @if (Model.level != 100)
                {
                    <h3 class="pull-right no-top-margin">@Model.expToNextLevelInt EXP → Level @(Model.level + 1)</h3>
                }

                <h3 class="no-top-margin">@Model.experience EXP</h3>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and here is what happens on desktop and mobile.

[image: full screen]

[image]

is it to do with the ordering of my classes or their contents?
Thanks for any help

Comment: Which 2 columns you want in same row? Can you please post image as you want output?

Comment: The images (the butterfree, and it's types) are in one column, and the other information is in another column
On a small/extra small screen I want the images column to be on it's own row, and the same with the information column.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding to your question I am providing this solution.

change the `col-lg-4` to `col-md-4` this fixes the problem of the same display in desktop and tablet mode then remove the `col-sm-12` since bootstrap has a default property that after specified resolution sizes it goes to `col-xs-12` if not specified.

Try the below code.

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                <img class="dream" src="~/Content/Images/Pokemon/Dream/@(Model.dexNo).png" />
                <img class="sprite" src="~/Content/Images/Pokemon/Sprites/@(Model.spriteString)" />
                <div style="display:block">
                    <img class="type" src="~/Content/Images/Types/@(Model.type1Id).png" />
                    @if (Model.type2Id.HasValue)
                {
                        <img class="type" src="~/Content/Images/Types/@(Model.type2Id.Value).png" />
                    }
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <h4 class="pull-right">no. @Model.dexNoThreeDigits</h4>
                @if (Model.isOwner)
                {
                    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#renameModal" style="color:black;cursor:pointer;text-decoration:none;"><h1 class="large-text text-center">@Model.nickName</h1></a>
                }
                else
                {
                    <h1 class="large-text text-center">@Model.nickName</h1>
                }
                <h1 class="large-text text-center" style="font-style:italic;opacity:0.2;position:relative;top:-34px;left:81px;">the @Model.speciesName</h1>
                
                <h3 class="no-bottom-margin">Level @Model.level</h3>

                <div class="progress no-bottom-margin">
                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="@Model.expToNextLevelPercent"
                         aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:@(Model.expToNextLevelPercent)%">
                        <span class="sr-only">@(Model.expToNextLevelPercent)% Complete</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                @if (Model.level != 100)
                {
                    <h3 class="pull-right no-top-margin">@Model.expToNextLevelInt EXP → Level @(Model.level + 1)</h3>
                }

                <h3 class="no-top-margin">@Model.experience EXP</h3>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: it sounds like it should work, they are still on the same row like in the second photo